# setting image as submit button in html

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

at present am using code as follows in my view but the image is not displaying what i have given but it is working.

```
<input type="submit" id="button" name="submit" value="Generate Report" src="<?php echo base_url();?>images/Generatereports_btn.png" onmouseover="this.src='<?php echo base_url();?>images/Generatereports_high.png'" onmouseout="this.src='<?php echo base_url();?>images/Generatereports_btn.png'"/>
```

when am using the following code the image is displaying what i gave but am getting php error in controller and model. what was wrong am doing and how i have to use in order to make it work properly someone help me please thanks.

```
<input type="image" value="Generate Report" name="submit" id="button" src="<?php echo base_url();?>images/Generatereports_btn.png" alt="submit" onMouseOut="this.src='<?php echo base_url();?>images/Generatereports_btn.png'" onMouseOver="this.src='<?php echo base_url();?>images/Generatereports_high.png'>
```

my controller looks like

```
   function survey_demo_response()
{       
        $data['survey_details'] = $this->session->store['survey'];
        if (isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['submit'] == 'Generate Report') 
        {
            $questionData = $_POST['questions'];
        }
        if (empty($_POST['questions'])) 
        {           
            $questionData = 1;
        }
        $data['question'] = $this->report_model->get_response_question($questionData);
        $this->load->view('reports/survey_demo_response',$data);

}
```

the error am gettin is

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: questionData

Filename: admin/reports.php

Line Number: 90
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined offset: 0

Filename: models/report_model.php

Line Number: 1272
```

Comment: what error are you getting..? can you paste it in your question..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `$questionData` variable doesn't get initialized (first error). Consequently, you pass a non-set varable to `report_model`'s `get_response_question()`, which produces the second error.

Apparently, neither

```
    isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['submit'] == 'Generate Report'
```

nor

```
    empty($_POST['questions'])
```

is true.

Try setting `$questionData` to some default value *before* the `if`s.

**EDIT**, to respond to your comments: To avoid the errors, just do

```
    $data['survey_details'] = $this->session->store['survey'];
    $questionData="I'm a fallback!"; // <---- see?
    if (isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['submit'] == 'Generate Report')
```

...which answers your original question.

Comment: it is because of isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['submit'] == 'Generate Report' so what i have to do

Comment: I already told you: _Try setting `$questionData` to some default value before the `if`s_.

Comment: as i have edited my code above on clicking on submit the value is not getting submitted so the error is getting what i have to do for this. can you help me please. on clicking the image the value has to be posted to controller. thanks.

Comment: Are you referring to the `<input type="image"` version?

Comment: i have a doubt can we have some value and can we pass it when image was clicked. is it possible if so how to do that?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking. Can you post your whole html in a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) for me to review?

Comment: if we use a button when we click we can pass some value na in the same way can we pass value when clicking on a image.

Comment: An `<input type="image"....` is supposed to do exactly that. It's an "image" submit button.

Comment: _it is not working for me_ is not a piece of info I can use. Please post a fiddle as I mentioned above, so that you _make it possible for me to help you_.

Comment: Meanwhile, please consider accepting the answer, since it answers your original question. Thank you.